# Send POST request from AWS SES received email content

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm working to forward received email on AWS SES to slack webhook.
The workflow I tried is:
my personal email -> SES -> S3 -> Lambda -> POST Request

I've been stuck on this lambda function since its not sending post request to webhook url

```
from ast import parse
import boto3
import ConfigParser
import urllib3 
import json
from email.parser import FeedParser
from email.header import decode_header
http = urllib3.PoolManager() 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  try:
    record = event["Records"][0]
    bucket_region = record["awsRegion"]
    bucket_name =  record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
    mail_object_key = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
  
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=bucket_region)
    mail_object = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = mail_object_key)
    mail_body = ''
    try:
      mail_body = mail_object["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    except:
      mail_body = mail_object["Body"].read()
  
    parser = FeedParser()
    parser.feed(mail_body)
    parsed_mail = parser.close()
  
    (d_sub, sub_charset) = decode_header(parsed_mail['Subject'])[0]
    subject = d_sub.decode(sub_charset)
    payload = parsed_mail.get_payload(decode=parsed_mail['Content-Transfer-Encoding'])
    body_charset = parsed_mail.get_content_charset()
    body = payload.decode(body_charset)

    url = "MY_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL"
    msg = {
        "Content": parsed_mail
    }
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST',url, body=encoded_msg)
    print({
        "message": parsed_mail, 
        "status_code": resp.status, 
        "response": resp.data
    })
  except:
    print('Mail received, but I got some error.')
```

Could anyone please look out to my code?

This is the cloudwatch log when lambda event triggered.

```
START RequestId: 00f3e7db-807e-48e9-a775-6f0117431b83 Version: $LATEST
Mail received, but I got some error.
END RequestId: 00f3e7db-807e-48e9-a775-6f0117431b83
REPORT RequestId: 00f3e7db-807e-48e9-a775-6f0117431b83  Duration: 1933.59 ms    Billed Duration: 1934 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 317.15 ms
```

Comment: Do you see the Lambda being triggered in the corresponding [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html)? If so, what are the log entries?

Comment: Yeah lambda is being triggered when received mail from SES is put to S3 bucket, I've already updated the post with cloudwatch log when lambda triggered

Comment: `but I got some error.` is not optimal ;) Please replace with the following and update the actual error message: 
`except Exception as e:`
    `print getattr(e, 'message', repr(e))`